# Get href of the link when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using owl carousel & nivo-lightbox to show video in a popup, all this works fine but I want to grab the URL of YouTube so that I can update the database based on the video viewed.

I keep getting undefined error in what I have done

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeQLpV)

```
  $('a').nivoLightbox({
                effect: 'fade',
                clickOverlayToClose: false,
                onInit: function () { },
         beforeShowLightbox: function () {   },
         afterShowLightbox: function () {

                console.log("I am here");
                var vid =  $(this).attr("href");
                console.log("vid" + vid);
                updateVideo();
                }
   });

   function updateVideo() {
            console.log("I am here..in ");

   }
```

How can I get the YoutubeID in above case

Comment: you want the `video - href` on click or on plugin init.??

Comment: When i open the popop `afterShowLightbox` i need the url of the video that is being viewed or in popup

Answer (score 2):

Here it is. The DOM has been changed when `afterShowLightbox` is called.

Try below code to get the URL

```
var vid = $(e[0][0]).find('iframe').attr('src');
```

**Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLRjQY**

Check the URL in the browser console

```
afterShowLightbox: function (e) {
    console.log("I am here");
    //var vid =  $(this).attr("href");
    var vid = $(e[0][0]).find('iframe').attr('src');
    console.log("vid" + vid);
    updateVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in `beforeShowLightBox`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJwrqP

```
  beforeShowLightbox: function(ele) {
    var vid = $(this.el).attr("href");
    console.log("vid" + vid); //Call Update function
  },
```

Comment: i still get `vidundefined`

Comment: @Learning Check the demo link

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your click outside the lightbox.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".play-video-yt", function() {
  var vid = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log("vid: " + vid);
  updateVideo();
});

//$(".play-video-yt").click(function () {
$('a').nivoLightbox({
  effect: 'fade',
  clickOverlayToClose: false,
  onInit: function() {},
  beforeShowLightbox: function() {},
  afterShowLightbox: function() {

    // console.log("I am here");
    // var vid =  $(this).attr("href");
    // console.log("vid" + vid);
    // updateVideo();

  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change below code from

`var vid =  $(this).attr("href");`

To:

`var vid =  $('a').attr("href");`